# Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug error on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2

Tags: android

I have migrated my project from Android Studio 2.3.3 to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 and now my project won't run.

I get the following message in the console:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/kerningview-1.0.0.aar/ac0f6c2213c36fdc32039f51a20bac89/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/38.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-utils-25.3.1.aar/56e47cfd160ed843d4216890e0682023/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/60.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-analytics-11.2.0.aar/61d81afc363bc8c865c16245e72c4d3e/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/52.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/2a8e0aa38a2e21cb39e2f5a7d6704cbdc941da0/gson-2.8.1.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/25.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-iid-11.2.0.aar/9651e811bb6602fd5600e13c0f77df9f/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/54.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/mixpanel-android-5.0.2.aar/c5e3ba28099100a23d773854c2a084a0/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/41.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-media-compat-25.3.1.aar/0ce9f8c2bae8fd1a0c62c91b27e5dffc/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/66.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-common-11.2.0.aar/1331f5675014cd64782fd82fe1ba00a6/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/55.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v4-25.3.1.aar/0b7bcfd4905c5ac50204aa5421a48426/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/58.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-ui-25.3.1.aar/2b962af6d4052d7dcf1fe7b4fecffac6/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/67.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-iid-11.0.4.aar/fe5d1cfe286ef2ff895cb2a8243612ed/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/49.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-auth-11.0.4.aar/1dc6d7b9b9e417c0c02beb44f1f6074d/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/48.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.3.0/bcacde6a8ccedcc56c127403d26b76072fe6214d/retrofit-2.3.0.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/71.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/library-1.0.5.aar/b8951b6a291a5e6dcb10ad712260f63a/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/31.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/rxandroid-1.2.1.aar/5b18b7f07a2bab8a4a872f6e339e94a7/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/74.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/crashlytics-core-2.3.16.aar/d223925dea9b1eb279b3c2c1e6c1459c/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/6.jar --input /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/crashlytics-2.6.7.aar/547e70ef2f064a53ac01c4cfc61ec3ba/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/renderscript/lib/renderscript-v8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/rag-sdk-0.0.59-SNAPSHOT.aar/96c4cb4a5e44efcc26c2770128372010/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/realm-android-library-3.5.0.aar/66a749eaa9802bd2a98835757e92bac1/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-annotations/3.5.0/1e4b144dd28b139ae890ce2868979b12e1f2d7c7/realm-annotations-3.5.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/crashlytics-2.6.7.aar/547e70ef2f064a53ac01c4cfc61ec3ba/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/beta-1.2.4.aar/6d4eef69ef44bed79d4fdd2247bdaae5/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/crashlytics-core-2.3.16.aar/d223925dea9b1eb279b3c2c1e6c1459c/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/answers-1.3.12.aar/89897d5535ea1b02a80e118a43258084/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/fabric-1.3.16.aar/b226cc1baee0201e5da67c74787af982/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.newrelic.agent.android/android-agent/5.9.0/723eac3b1ab0217e2cb04831ada6dcdb6182ea35/android-agent-5.9.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/multidex-1.0.2.aar/ab83d031af915067cc7a0c9ca075cb05/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/facebook-android-sdk-4.19.0.aar/7d4a78fd6e6d7cfc85dee6f3475508af/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/cardview-v7-25.3.1.aar/0502c0da0d735bd478f1167a4a6f704f/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/flexbox-0.3.0-alpha3.aar/39dfb9239b492f7099409b4793e918d6/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/materialdatetimepicker-3.1.3.aar/0ac5fa2cafae94963c888a03c2066d62/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/account-kit-sdk-4.13.2.aar/968ce87dabb0a8f5e2e9d45f071da1fd/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/7d60cd51bf1b35f70790140c93c133d1/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.aar/66d87d379811b0222f7d29e88d7ee4b4/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/palette-v7-25.3.1.aar/886a5a593100fca9ff7d285cebea9c43/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-location-11.0.4.aar/d6ab8ba223c68ddb65470db31d7257e4/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-pinpoint/2.3.9/2411e971f75652b978b550b7a8021af84e36d954/aws-android-sdk-pinpoint-2.3.9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-sns/2.3.9/4a9c68c102c695a24eb9bba09f8a472e576614e5/aws-android-sdk-sns-2.3.9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-sqs/2.3.9/a1278f3266ff8c936dd0de6485de8029a900091f/aws-android-sdk-sqs-2.3.9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-core/2.3.9/2fa9ee0e95329912656c8ccd98991b195a3ea539/aws-android-sdk-core-2.3.9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-gson/2.3.0/9e09011e9767bb76b5e27c9b8223476b93b14631/converter-gson-2.3.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/2a8e0aa38a2e21cb39e2f5a7d6704cbdc941da0/gson-2.8.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/glide-transformations-2.0.1.aar/b078f70cacc24be94b8b93325260dc09/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.7.0/9e9eeaf9948ee4d6c3ab354e8dc14368f16994a4/glide-3.7.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/circleimageview-1.3.0.aar/de80af8de5f58d8c8d206f6a155983f9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/exoplayer-r2.3.1.aar/d2ae88c982af4647796c9970fc6e1a7f/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/calligraphy-2.1.0.aar/d339434857786078a339f7bb8c6b1b89/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/library-1.0.5.aar/b8951b6a291a5e6dcb10ad712260f63a/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nineoldandroids/library/2.4.0/e9b63380f3a242dbdbf103a2355ad7e43bad17cb/library-2.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4/5fe28b9518e58819180a43a850fbc0dd24b7c050/commons-lang3-3.4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-core-11.2.0.aar/6e48ed999582b07f13647c34ee52888a/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/android-adapters-2.1.0.aar/08d283ad9c4b052ffca9c687dc1e3b2b/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.parceler/parceler-api/1.1.6/2a06b6b1ecf5dadee8a874dfb51ad018fde3e6c5/parceler-api-1.1.6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/butterknife-8.4.0.aar/05f8241e57862f51f79e0523d0e3d1bc/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/kerningview-1.0.0.aar/ac0f6c2213c36fdc32039f51a20bac89/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.flurry.android/analytics/6.4.2/4e6af3e20aff7888244687a9767b872e3881e822/analytics-6.4.2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-gcm-11.0.4.aar/fad45efecbb74c6eff162197b1eb1fa4/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/mixpanel-android-5.0.2.aar/c5e3ba28099100a23d773854c2a084a0/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/ThinDownloadManager-1.3.0.aar/03e18d87a8d20f9b1944e3d16d68410e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.airbnb/deeplinkdispatch/3.1.0/de0fff5510aa9b3e76e17c498f342b07577cb3fa/deeplinkdispatch-3.1.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/relinker-1.2.2.aar/80ef4959756399d4d7a9a9b9607b5521/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v13-25.2.0.aar/458c952d56ef1958492460222a5c9ad4/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar/2b65524bb1dfaff43f55e61a19dff5cb/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/transition-25.3.1.aar/8839b5b51b1844f4f1e76b9bc7d7a829/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-auth-11.0.4.aar/1dc6d7b9b9e417c0c02beb44f1f6074d/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-iid-11.0.4.aar/fe5d1cfe286ef2ff895cb2a8243612ed/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-auth-base-11.0.4.aar/3aadee1c07f32f8fc543bb6a63735ca5/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-base-11.0.4.aar/7731a52a7fbaa035349a55580682b05a/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-analytics-11.2.0.aar/61d81afc363bc8c865c16245e72c4d3e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-analytics-impl-11.2.0.aar/ad4e6f99304117dc73c1d3b3b05760c9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-iid-11.2.0.aar/9651e811bb6602fd5600e13c0f77df9f/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-common-11.2.0.aar/1331f5675014cd64782fd82fe1ba00a6/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-tasks-11.2.0.aar/3e38d10ec79889323875e738fb65f287/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-basement-11.2.0.aar/e42f11c2ca206625f2890cd632bd6348/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v4-25.3.1.aar/0b7bcfd4905c5ac50204aa5421a48426/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-fragment-25.3.1.aar/cd529e7062b915abaaddf7f4d73cfac9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-utils-25.3.1.aar/56e47cfd160ed843d4216890e0682023/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jakewharton/butterknife-annotations/8.4.0/ea392375cf9ff59234a82e7928a204215ccc98cd/butterknife-annotations-8.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/material-spinner-1.1.0.aar/a1910f9ec27381bd317b2a22c9a2854e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/customtabs-25.0.0.aar/bacef9854d041e1a23293966aab92c92/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1.aar/89ce02079a4f07a6e037eb99535be98c/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-vector-drawable-25.3.1.aar/8ff74f175af9b6abba76eb3fa140cc20/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-media-compat-25.3.1.aar/0ce9f8c2bae8fd1a0c62c91b27e5dffc/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-ui-25.3.1.aar/2b962af6d4052d7dcf1fe7b4fecffac6/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-25.3.1.aar/3f45f1063eae680ce7cef7112056c988/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.3.1/support-annotations-25.3.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.3.0/43e4ac24adc40a24c51b2d2a71a2483ef1b0ce9a/adapter-rxjava-2.3.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.3.0/bcacde6a8ccedcc56c127403d26b76072fe6214d/retrofit-2.3.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.8.1/4d060ca3190df0eda4dc13415532a12e15ca5f11/okhttp-3.8.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.greenrobot/eventbus/3.0.0/ddd99896e9569eaababbe81b35d80e1b91c4ad85/eventbus-3.0.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/rxandroid-1.2.1.aar/5b18b7f07a2bab8a4a872f6e339e94a7/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.3.0/af000bec2036a2a9d07197c4b03b8966bfc60b03/rxjava-1.3.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.13.0/a9283170b7305c8d92d25aff02a6ab7e45d06cbe/okio-1.13.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1/f7be08ec23c21485b9b5a1cf1654c2ec8c58168d/jsr305-3.0.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-android/1.4.0/cc174c559b5177982887bf6e1b76003aebad9516/bolts-android-1.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-applinks/1.4.0/8ad21bf21784dacce5f2043afb97218cc377e835/bolts-applinks-1.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-tasks/1.4.0/d85884acf6810a3bbbecb587f239005cbc846dc4/bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/pq/Radio Africa/NakedGroove/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --bootclasspath_entry /Users/pq/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/pq/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 19 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

Is there anything I'm missing to make it run?

My gradle file is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.9.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven" }
    maven {
        url "http://nexus.radioafricaplatforms.com/repository/radio-africa-group"
        credentials {
            username "${project.getProperties().ragNexusUsername}"
            password "${project.getProperties().ragNexusPassword}"
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.radioafrica.music"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 74
        versionName "0.9.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        multiDexKeepProguard file("proguard.multidex.config")
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

//    retrolambda {
//        jvmArgs '-noverify'
//    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.16@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.radioafrica.sdk:rag-sdk:0.0.59-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.andrognito.kerningview:kerningview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-pinpoint:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.0.2"
    compile 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0-alpha3'
    compile 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch:3.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch-processor:3.1.0'
//    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.4-2"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya check updated question for `build.gradle`

Comment: use `compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"`

Comment: I have updated my question need solution

Comment: Just started getting this

Comment: I have solved my problem with the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645163/lombok-1-18-2-throws-transformclasseswithdexbuilderfordebug

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   java process with main class
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments

Open your <kbd>build.gradle</kbd> and use below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .

Comment: Since Android Studio 3.0 is out, minimum required `buildToolsVersion` is `26.0.2`, however, executing `clean` and `build` still helped me in a similar situation, everything works now. And I thought invalidating Android Studio cache would help, but no

Comment: Hello, this doesn't work for me. i am using android studion 3.0.1.please suggest any other solution.

Comment: The point is update `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolVersion` to the newest then `Clean` and `Rebuild`

Comment: I haven't changed a thing just added some new classes and code and I get this error.  I did a clean rebuild and still the same result.  Thing was I just built about 1 hour ago and it was fine.

Answer (score 32):

I faced with this issue in an ionic cordova project

the solution was a clean of the project :

> cordova clean android

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks very much. This solution also works for ionic builds

Comment: I tried all the solution here but nothing work :(. I also use IONIC.

Answer (score 8):

change your porject/build.gralde

```
compileOptions {
    //sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    //targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

rebuild .......ok,
I change this file. rebuild ......Compile apk successfully!
Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, when i commented those out, it works, but the problem is i need to use java 8

Comment: Same here, after removing Java 1.8 from build.gradle the error is gone. However does anybody knows how to enable Java 1.8 without issues?

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed it by removing the "build/intermediates" directory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed source compatibility and target compatibility from 1.8 to 1.7, and everything started to work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` must be the same version, especially `compileSdkVersion`. Because if you don't define `compileSdkVersion`, the last version import automatically, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a Flutter project. I'm currently using Android Studio 3.5.2 and I could fix the issue as following:

1. In the project build.gradle file, I upgraded to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'`
2. In gradle-wrapper.properties file, I upgraded to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

You can check the Android Gradle plugin versions from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle).