# Execution failed for task ' transformclasseswithdesugarformobiledebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I keep getting this error since I have updated my studio to stable version 3.0. Earlier I was working on preview 3.0

```
execution failed for task ' transformclasseswithdesugarformobiledebug'
```

After this, only option I am left with to clean the project and re-run which takes almost 10-15 mins.

Is there any permanent solution for this?

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug error on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833937/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdesugarfordebug-error-on-andro)

Comment: @AesSedai101 not the same error.

Comment: When this happens, for me it's usually jdk holding the file handle by mistake. Closing studio (kill the jdk in task manager manually if it's still there), delete build folder manually and try again. Usually fixes that