# ErrorExecution failed

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio 3.0, I have no problem with importing the project

but when i run that this error appears as

> ErrorExecution failed for task
>   'apptransformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException
>   java.lang.RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException Error while executing
>   java process with main class
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments
>   {@CUsersASADIDesktopSaifChatSoftappbuildintermediatestmpdesugar_args27136588803337456}

how can i fix that?

Comment: Have a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833937/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdesugarfordebug-error-on-andro) SO question.

Comment: I took a look before but could not find a solution

Comment: please help me. search a lot but dont find any answer