# Android Studio Error : app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.io.IOException: Could not delete path'C:\Users\1447065\AndroidStudioProjects\Teest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\1.jar'.

Please help me to solve this. Everytime this issue occur i rebuild/clean the project then again i take 20 minutes to build my project.

**Using Android Studio Version 3.0.1
Build Version 27.0.1**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug error on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833937/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdesugarfordebug-error-on-andro)

Comment: Have you tried by manually deleting the file? `C:\Users\1447065\AndroidStudioProjects\Teest\clientapp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\1.jar`

Comment: @Signo i tried this way also, the error will resolve and again my app will build take 25 minutes

Comment: @HemantParmar in my case  compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

Comment: I have same problem and strange that on mac os all works