# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic for my mobile application. When I am using

```
ionic cordova build android
```

getting following error :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.Runtime
```

How can I fix this build issue ?  I tried :

```
cordova clean android
```

But no luck issue is still existing. Please suggest one solution to fix this issue.

Actual error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED
```

build.gradle file dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.+"
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Comment: Many possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833937/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdesugarfordebug-error-on-andro

Comment: @JakeSteam i tried all these solutions but its not working

Comment: Can you try posting the rest of your error please, specifically the actual stack trace that usually appears just before the "what went wrong"?

Comment: @JakeSteam updated error what i am getting on my end

Comment: Can you show your app level `build.gradle`? [This issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2247) looks very similar.

Comment: updated dependencies in app level build.gradle

Comment: Could you list the plugins you have installed? could you post your project.properties file? And also: did the app used to compile? when did it stop? was it after you installed a cordova plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your dependencies classes is not defined properly so first check your google dependencies in build.gradle,All dependencies should be same version.

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

if still got an error then open android studio and build it using SDK, in this solution if some of the your dependencies setup not correct that sdk resolve your error automatically or give you alternative to update your dependencies,I recommend to build it through SDK it will solve your problem.

Comment: Which build.gradle ?. I tried In app build.gradle but its not working

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,now try to build your project in android studio if it's a version mismatch problem then android sdk gives you an error with option to update gradle then update it ,it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by a version mismatch; most likely these are at fault:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.+"
```

can build against current API level `28`, with current build-tools `28.0.3`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17"
}
```